# How to replace Lohit Bengali font in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: fonts

The default font for Bengali language is Lohit Bengali. But it is ugly and I don't like this font. So I want to replace it with a font called Bangla.

Or, I want to set Bangla as default Bengali font systemwide instead of Lohit Bengali. I'm not asking about how to change it on Chrome, Firefox, LibreOffice etc. I want to change the system font. I can change the English font with Gnome Tweak Tool. But there is no option for native language fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have system-wide default fonts and what you are seeing is the Bangla glyphs of those fonts. You can change it in Tweaks. Here is my setup,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked while ago but I was looking for same type of solution and didn't find much. As I am using **"Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"** `lohit-bengali` was default in my system and web interface.

What I did is removed `lohit-bengali`, `lohit-assamese`, `font-beng-extra` and `freefont` directories from `/usr/share/fonts/truetype` directory, then I downloaded `Noto Sans Bengali` from [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Bengali) extracted it, moved the font directory in `/usr/share/fonts/truetype` directory and reboot; voila! This will apply on system interface as well as web and other applications like libreoffice.

Note:

1. Will require root privilege to removing and moving with recursive flag;
2. I think GNU `freefont` makes conflict with default/other bangla fonts style, I just removed all and installed my prefered one;
3. For bangla fonts in repository `apt-cache search bengali` and install it `sudo apt-get install <font-name>`;

[আমি বাংলায় কথা কই](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAe6s.png)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, I did something like @MSRhmn said back then. For new users with relatively little or no experience in handling system files, this can be 'risky'.

Back then I used to distro hop too frequently. Downloading, deleting, and messing with system fonts in every distro was a boring task. So I came up with a new idea. I merged my favorite English and Bangla font into a single custom font with FontForge and set that as the system-wide interface font.

For those who don't know: merging fonts is super easy. Since English is the simplest language, start with the Bangla (or any language that is more complex than English) font you like.

- Open both fonts in FontForge
- Copy English glyphs (characters) from the English font and paste those into the target font.
- Change the name, metadata of the new font. Make sure to follow the licensing terms of both fonts.<sup>[1]</sup>
- Export the font in `.ttf` or `.otf` format.

There are a few things to keep in mind though. The 'Em Size', 'Ascent', 'Descent' etc. should be similar. Especially the Em Size is important. You can scale any font to a certain Em Size right from FontForge (it is a great free open-source tool). Make sure you scale both fonts to the same Em Size before merging.

Although it is a dead simple task, just opening two files and copy-pasting, it is still good to have some basic knowledge regarding fonts. [FontForge Docs](https://fontforge.org/en-US/documentation/) can be a good place to start.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> For example, you can happily modify any font with [SIL Open Font License](https://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=OFL). Make sure to change the font name, so it does not confuse people between original vs modified work.